# Retain the Select All button in a custom React-Admin Datagrid header

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I'm using a custom Datagrid header in my React-Admin app. The docs show [a way](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Datagrid.html#header) to place an empty cell in the header to account for the select row checkbox.

That works great. But instead of the empty cell, I'd like to leave the "select all" checkbox in place in my custom DatagridHeader. I only want to customize column header text. Is there any way to do this?

```
const DatagridHeader = ({ children }) => (
    <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
            {/* Can i retain the "select all" in the TableCell below? */}
            <TableCell></TableCell> {/* empty cell */}
            {Children.map(children, child => (
                <TableCell key={child.props.source}>
                    field: {child.props.label}
                </TableCell>
            ))}
        </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set headers of columns (fields) through the translation files: [Translating Resource and Field Names](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/TranslationTranslating.html#translating-resource-and-field-names).
You can also explicitly override title by setting 'label' field attribute:

```
<Datagrid>
  <TextField source="id" label="Custom header" />
  ...
</Datagrid>
```